# Can I have a form inside a site master in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: webforms

I am trying to insert a form into my site.Master but when I debug it, it seems to have removed the form.

```
<form onsubmit="quoteMe(event)">
    <div class="form-group" id="divQuotePriceBeforeBook">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="quotemebutton" type="submit">Quote Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I can see that there is a server form wrapping the entire body, does this mean we can't have forms?

Comment: Why do you want a form within a form? That’s just not compatible with how Web Forms does things. A good solution is to not use Web Forms - that’s a serious suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that using WebForms but there is always a work around.

Based off of your code it doesn't seem like you need a form for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
<div class="form-group" id="divQuotePriceBeforeBook">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="quotemebutton" onclick="quoteMe()">Quote Now</button>
</div>
```

If you really do need the code to post back to the server, you would want to do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="divQuotePriceBeforeBook">
    <asp:Button id="quotemebutton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-primary" OnClientClick="quoteMe()" Text="Quote Now" />
</div>
```